# Feedback for a Point Buy System for Spellcreation/Research

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, crafting

I'm working on an RPG as a class project that uses 3.5e rules, and as a experiment I created a point buy system for spell creation rules.

Its a very rough second draft that seems to come out roughly right for fireball, I'd appreciate any input on its balance.

There's obviously some things missing and some of it should be marked as can only being in use in conjunction with some of the other properties, but as I said, second draft.

I'm looking for any and all feedback to make it "more balanced", i.e closing obvious brokenness that may exist within it.

Also if you see anything "missing" that I don't have an apparent stub or placeholder for don't be afraid to add suggestions!

```
/***SPELL CREATION***/

To research a new spell the wizard must have access to a library.
    * Within library with a crafting table(?)
1000gp * per week.
1 week * spell level.

/*** POINTS SYSTEM ***/

For every concrete parameter the spell has, it gains "cost" in points, this cost is either
bought off by increasing the spell level, or through limiting useful or adding costs to cast.

TO CREATE A SPELL THERE MUST NOT BE AN EXCESS OF MORE THAN ONE "POINT" OUTSTANDING.

All spells marked {D} must have a duration.

COST INCREASES
-----------------
IMMEDIATE CASTING TIME: +15.
ILLUSION: +25
/* Okay, this one's weird. You can make any spell an illusion spell,
* and that's a +25; and everything else applies normally.
* The thing is, now it must automatically get a "disbelief" saving
* throw. I know its weird to summon an "illusory" adamantine wall be 
* more expensive than a rock wall or something, just roll with it.
* Pretend that making a wall look more menancing is more difficult
* to pull off.
*/

/*** ENERGY & HP DAMAGE SUBSTITUTION ***/
BLUDGEON: +0
SLASHING: +0
PIERCING: +0
ELECTRICITY: +0
COLD: +0
SONIC ENERGY TYPE: +10

/****** HP DAMAGE **********/
1d6 Damage Die: +6/Die.
1d8 Damage: +8/Die.
1d10 Damage: +10/Die.

/****** RANGE **********/
/*
*   A spell can only have 
*   "One" and only one "range"
*   ALL Spells must have this.
*
*/

PERSONAL: +0
TOUCH: +5
CLOSE: +10
MEDIUM Range: +15
LONG: +35
WORLD: +250 //ANYWHERE on the current World.
PLANE: +500 //Anywhere on the current Plane of existence.

/************ STATUS EFFECT ************/
/*
*   "DIE" & other DEATH EFFECTS MUST
*   Have a "Saving Throw" See 
*   "Saving Throws".
*/
LOSE STATUS EFFECT*: +25
DIE STATUS EFFECT**: +150
SUCK STATUS EFFECT*: +10

/**** BUFFS {D} ****/
/* All must have Duration */
"BUFF" STATUS EFFECT: +30 /* Can stack with multiple different buffs */
/*** & CHOOSE ONE ***/
+X to Ability Score: +15(X)
+X Temporary HP: +2(X)
+X Base(?) AC: +20(X)
+X Natural AC: +25(X)
+X Shield-AC: +25(X)
DR X (Any material/damagetype): +15(X)
+X Attack Rolls: +15(X)
+X Skillcheck: +15(X)
+X Caster level: +50(X)
+X Spell Penetration: +45(X)
MISS CHANCE +5(X)%: +50(X)
+X(%) ENERGY RESISTANCE: +25(X)
+X Spell Resistance: +20(X)
+X To Saving Throw: +15(X)
// *** BLah blah blah 

/*** "THREAT" ***/
/*
*   Should you stack a status effect with
*   ANY other effect, such as Damage, or
*   Battlefield Control, automatically add
*   "Double Threat", and then "+THREAT" for
*   Every additional discrete effect.
*/
DOUBLE THREAT: +20
+THREAT: +10

/********* TARGETS & AREA *********/
/*
* Some spells let you choose individual
* targets or have a AREA of effect.
* You may only choose individual targets OR
* a type of AREA.
*/
/** SINGLE TARGETS 88?
+Single Target: +5
+Single Target/3 Caster Levels: +3
+Single Target/5 Caster Levels: +1
/*** AREA ***/
/* First choose a type. */
* ONLY ONE AND AT LEAST ONE.
*/
BURST: +0
SPREAD: +0
EMANATION: +0 /** NB: MUST HAVE DURATION **/
/**** SHAPE ****/
CONE: +5
CYLINDER: +5
LINE: +0
SPHERE: +0
/*** MUST have an Area of effect/size.***/
Area of Effect: +5+X, where X=Every 5 feet inspread >5.
Shapeable: +10

/**** BATTLEFIELD CONTROL ****/
SUMMON MONSTER: +[(10 * CR) * N MONSTERS]
SUMMON CONCEALMENT/COVER (See Material Chart): +25+X: X=MATERIAL 
SUMMON ENERGY: +150 // MUST HAVE DURATION
SUMMON FORCE: +250
TRANSMUTE MATERIAL TO MATERIAL: +25 + 5
// NB: Where X is the number of steps removed from base material //
PLANAR TRAVEL: +450 // Plane to Plane
TELEPORTATION: +250 // See Range Rules.


Duration Chart (*: Must have Duration)
--------------
Effective Caster Level * Seconds: +0
Effective Caster Level * 10/Seconds: +5
Effective Caster Level * Minute: +15
Effective Caster Level * 10/Minute: +20
Effective Caster Level * Hour: +25
Effective Caster Level * Day: +35
PERMAMENT: +50.

/***** COST DECREASERS PER CASTING:*****/
XP COST *100XP: -15.
GP COST *100GP: -10.
+1 SPELL LEVEL: -20.
CONCNETRATION CHECK 10+SPELL LEVEL+X: -10+(X*2).
FIRE ENERGY TYPE: -5. // Because really, fire sucks.

/*** SAVING THROWS ***/ (**: Death Effects MUST have a Saving Throw)
SAVING THROW FOR HALF: -10.
SAVING THROW TO NEGATE: -15.
SAVING THROW TO PARTIAL: -5.
DISBELIEF: -15. // MUST be an illusion spell.
SPELL RESISTANCE: -15.
FULL ROUND CASTING TIME: -15.
X/Minute CASTING TIME: -15*X.
RAY: -10.
HARMLESS: -5. //How does this...? :psyduck:
CASTING COMPONENTS: -5/Component.
/* chanting, gestures, materials */

/***** MATERIALS *****/
MIST: +0 /** HAS COUNTER WITH ANY "WIND" or FIRE Spell **/
SPIDERSILK: +2
WOOD: +5
IRON: +10
MITHRIL: +15
ADAMANTINE: +25

EXAMPLE: FIREBALL COST:
Damage: 10d6 = 60.
Range: FAR = +25
Area: 20" = +15.

SUBTOTAL: 100 POINTS.
-5 for fire.
-15 Spell resistance.
-10 saving throw for half.
COMPONENTS: [S], [V], [M] =-15.
SPELL LEVEL: 3=-60.

TOTAL COST: -5 points.~About right.
```

Comment: I'm not sure we'll be able to help you very much with general feedback; it's not the best kind of question for a Q&A format. Do you have a specific area you'd like to see improve, or something in particular you'd like suggestions on?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)! Emrakul has this one right I think. This site is primarily aimed at questions with straightforward answers, less so than a discussion style format that something like this would entail. It's an interesting system though.

Comment: This isn't a forum guys, please keep it to the format.

Comment: Whoops sorry, hit reopen accidentally.  So this could be an answerable question, though on our Meta people express strong preference for you to have used the rules in play before springing them on us - http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/987/are-questions-requesting-reviews-of-work-on-topic and http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/942/how-to-deal-with-feedback-questions-about-house-rules and http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2912/homebrew-evaluation-questions.  I think talking with people in chat would be better during this phase.